# Send data from one array object into another array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got an Object Array:

```
hm.push(member.personal);
console.log("New input: " + ko.toJSON(hm));
server.insertPersonalInformacion(ko.toJS(hm));
```

Console.log output:

```
[{
    "personalInfo": {},
    "adresaInfo": {},
    "Telefone": [{
        numer1: ,
        callNumb:
    }],
    "Mobile": [{}],
    "emailAdrese": [{
        email:
    }]
}]
```

Now i would like to place this Array Object into another Object:

```
var insertPersonalInformacion = function(inputInfo) {
    memberData.personal.forEach(function(p) {
        p.personalInfo.push(inputInfo);

        "And here i am lost"
        );

        });
    });
};
```

This is the call object

```
  var memberData = {
      personal: [{
          "personalInfo": {},
          "adresaInfo": {},
          "Telefone": [{
              numer1: ,
              callNumb:
          }],
          "Mobile": [{}],
          "emailAdrese": [{
              email:
          }]
      }]
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exact question is not quite clear, mainly because your variable identifiers seem a bit inconsistent throughout the code snippets.

If you want to assign your array to `memberData.personal`, a simple assignment will do:

```
var memberData = {
    personal: yourArray
};
```

To merge the existing array content of `memberData.personal` with your array, use `Array.prototype.concat()`:

```
var memberData.personal = memberData.personal.concat(yourArray);
```